# State in useState does not change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a functional component

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

export default function AboutUs() {
const [counter,setCounter] = useState(0);

const clicked = () => {
    setCounter(counter+1);
}

return (
    <div>
        <p>you clicked {counter} times</p>
        <button onClick={clicked}>Click</button>        
    </div>
)
}
```

there is nothing wrong with that and it works just fine. But when I remove onClick in button element and add the event listener like:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

export default function AboutUs() {
const [counter,setCounter] = useState(0);

useEffect(()=>{
    document.getElementById('test').addEventListener('click',clicked);
},[])

const clicked = () => {
    setCounter(counter+1);
}

return (
    <div>
        <p>you clicked {counter} times</p>
        <button id="test">Click</button>        
    </div>
)
}
```

after one click **counter** value will be 1 and then it stops!
the **counter** does not change by **setCounter** anymore!
what is wrong with that?
I would appreciate your help.

Comment: What's the reason using tricky DOM selector instead of using `onClick` as in the first example?

Comment: You are manipulating DOM on React... Bad idea....

Comment: my problem was not about just a simple onClick, it is clear we can do it like the first part. I had a problem with `window.addEventListener("deviceorientation", handleOrientation, true);` which is about gyroscope. Luckily **Quentin** answered that. @lazy.lizard and @Giovanni Esposito

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I have a functional component

You do not.

Your component tracks state which violates the principle of functional programming that says functions should have **no side effects**.

You have a **function component**.

---

> the counter does not change by setCounter anymore!

The event handler is attached in a `useEffect` hook.

That hook gets called when the component first mounts and when any of the dependencies change.

The dependencies list is `[]` so the dependancies will never change.

Each time it is called (which we've just established is only once) it will create a function that [closes over](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) the `counter` constant (initially set to `0`)

Each time the element is clicked on you'll get `setCounter(counter+1);` where `counter` is always `0` because that is the value of the constant that was closed over.

(Even though changing the state triggers a re-render which creates a **different constant with the same name**).

---

To do this using that approach you would generally do something like this:

```
useEffect(()=>{
    document.getElementById('test').addEventListener('click',clicked);
    return () => document.getElementById('test').removeEventListener('click', 'clicked');
},[clicked])
```

So each time the function changes it cleans up the previous event listener and adds the new one (which has closed over the new constant)

---

But direct DOM manipulation is fragile and throws away the main benefits of React. So **don't do that**. Use the `onClick={click}` approach, that is how React is designed to work.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 problems here:

1. `useEffect` dependency is not specified
2. `useEffect` does not have a cleanup handler
   Updating your code would give something like this:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const element = document.getElementById('test');
  element.addEventListener('click', clicked);
  return () => { element.removeEventListener('click', clicked) };
}, [clicked]);
```

But an issue remains: the `clicked` function reference changes at each render which means that the `useEffect` will remove/add the listener at every render.
To avoid this, you should wrap your clicked handler in a `useCallback` with proper dependencies like this:

```js
const clicked = useCallback(() => {
    setCounter(counter + 1);
}, [counter]);
```